# What is the best practice for displaying huge chat logs or console logs in a scrollable window? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, chat, display

I'm writing a graphic console that highlights different entries and stores things when you input them (in AS3) but I've found that once there are thousands of entries, the program starts lagging and scrolling is slow. If I want scrolling to be animated with acceleration it gets even slower.

How do I move the giant block of objects that are my stored entries up and down?
Do I have to progressively load messages around where the user is looking? How does the scrollbar handle this, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create a custom container instead `TextField`, it would be easier to build an accelerated scrolling too,

- each log entry would be an extended DisplayObject that holds anything you want just like inflating layouts in android.

the most important part should be reducing Memory usage:

- you may only store plain text of log enteries in something like a global array and when scroll position is close enough, generate this layouts, then adding them in container to show, and vice versa for removing far behind chats.
  however this proccess stills using much memory during runtime.
- so, just according the concept of android's **`DiskLruCache`**, it is possible to storing some part of our invisible data which would be too far from our scroll position to disk instead memory, using **[`SharedObject's`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I move the giant block of objects that are my stored entries up
>   and down?

You don't. As you have noticed, when the number `Display Objects`on the `DisplayList` greatly increases, the memory overhead increases and the housekeeping details of managing the `Display Objects`eventually causes performance to suffer. You don't mention any details of how you are implementing what you have so far so my comments will be general.

The way this is handled by various platform **list components** in Flex, iOS and I assume, Flash, is to only display the minimum number of objects needed, and as the user scrolls, objects are shuffled in and out of the render list. A further optimization is to use a "pool" of "template" objects which are reused so you don't pay a initialization time penalty. There is probably an actual name for this ("...buffering...") technique but I don't know what it is (hopefully some kind person will provide it and a link to a fuller description for how it works).

And as for how it works – you can DIY it, figuring out, as the user scrolls, which objects are moving off-screen and can be recycled, which are going to move on-screen, etc. Of course this all assumes that you have your objects stored in a data structure like and `Array`, `ArrayList` or `ArrayCollection`. As an alternative to coding all this from scratch, you might see if the [DataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html) or [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/List.html) components will meet your needs – they manage all of this for you.

[Flash Tutorial: The DataGrid Component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEauFqZbJTw) (youTube video)
[Customize the List component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f41.html)
Lots of other examples and resources out there.

*(again, I work in Flex where the DataGrid and other list-based components can customized extensively using "skins" and custom item renderers for visual style – not sure if it is the same in Flash)*

Comment: "*pay a initialization time penalty*" as far as what I've seen, it's more of a destruction time penalty. The garbage collector keeps piling up garbage until some threshold is reached. Then it kicks in actually deleting the objects which itself requires a bit of performance, which can lead to skipped frames. Preventing objects from being collected by the GC, forcing them to stay in memory and reusing them to not run out of memory is a technique called "object pooling".